# Localization of euclidean ring is euclidean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

I am trying to prove that a localization of a euclidean ring is euclidean, and the converse statement.

I feel the basic definition of the norm is enough but I do not know how.

Please note I am very much a beginner in abstract algebra.

Comment: There is no way the converse is true. Consider $R=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times\cdots$ (countably infinite product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$). Then $R$ is not Noetherian (so not a Euclidean domain), but localization at every prime ideal is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is a field (and so a Euclidean domain).

Comment: @Prism I find your example irrelevant. It addresses more to the integral domain property (showing that is not local). I think the question is the following: Let $R$ be an integral domain and $S\subset R$ a multiplicative set. Then $R$ is euclidean iff $S^{-1}R$ is euclidean. Of course, the converse is trivially wrong. But even if we want to show that the euclidean property is not local we have to consider integral domains, and then a Dedekind domain which is not a UFD (like $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}])$ is doing the job.

Comment: @user26857: You are right, of course. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ example is better and more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

For one direction, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1748047/11653). The converse is not true: Given any integral domain $R$, you can localize at $S:=R\setminus\{0\}$ and obtain a field $S^{-1}R=\operatorname{Frac}(R)$, which is a Euclidean domain. However, there are integral domains which are not Euclidean, for example $R=\mathbb Q[X,Y]$. Note that $R$ is not Euclidean because it is not a principal ideal domain.