# Localization Preserves Euclidean Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-algorithm, localization

I'm wanting to prove that given a ring $A$ (by "ring" I mean a *commutative* ring with *identity*) and a multiplicative subset $S \subset A$:

> if $A$ is an Euclidean Domain, and $0 \notin S$ then $S^{-1}A$ (localization of A at S) is also an Euclidean Domain.

I'm trying to produce an Euclidean Function in $S^{-1}A$ using the Euclidean Function $N:A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, that I already have from $A$ but I'm having trouble trying to define it in a way that works and verifies the properties an Euclidean Function must verify.

Does any one mind giving me hints? I don't really want a solution.. I would like to work it myself.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [wikipedia's language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain), we may assume that $N$ satisfies $N(a)\le N(ab)$ for $a,b\in A$. Let us denote the candidate function for the localization by $N_S\colon (S^{-1}A)\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb N$.

We will also replace $S$ by its saturation, i.e. by $S_{\mathrm{sat}}:=\{ a\in A \mid \exists b\in A: ab\in S\}$. Notice that $S_{\mathrm{sat}}^{-1}A=S^{-1}A$ because for any $a\in S_{\mathrm{sat}}$, we have $a^{-1}=\frac{b}{s}\in S^{-1}A$ where $b\in A$ and $s\in S$ are such that $s= ab$. Hence, assume henceforth that $S$ is saturated in the sense that for any $a\in A$, if there exists some $b\in A$ with $ab\in S$, then we have $a\in S$.

Hint:

> First, note that you may assume $N_S(s)=1$ for all $s\in S$. Indeed, for any $a\in S^{-1}A$, you have $N_S(s)\le N_S(\frac as\cdot s)=N_S(a)$. Hence, $N_S(s)$ must be minimal. Argue similarly that $N_S(\frac 1s)=1$ for $s\in S$. Now use the fact that $A$ is a unique factorization domain.

Full spoiler, hover for reveal:

> We first note that an Element $s\in S$ can not have any prime factor in $A\setminus S$. Indeed, let $s=s_1\cdots s_n$ be the prime factors of $s$. Then, $s_1\in S$ and $s_2\cdots s_n\in S$ because $S$ is saturated. Proceed by induction.
>  
>  For $\frac{ta}{s}\in S^{-1}A$, with $t,s\in S$ and $a$ not divisible by any element of $S$, let $N_S\left(\frac{ta}{s}\right):=N(a)$. This is well-defined because if $\frac{t_1a_1}{s_1}=\frac{t_2a_2}{s_2}$, then $s_1t_2a_2=s_2t_1a_1$. Since $a_1$ is not divisible by any element of $S$, it contains no prime factor in $S$. Since $s_2t_1\in S$, it contains no prime factor in $A\setminus S$. This argument symmetrically works for $s_1t_2\cdot a_1$ and it follows that $s_1t_2=s_2t_1$ and (more importantly) $a_1=a_2$.
>  
>  Now we prove that $N_S$ yields a degree function turning $S^{-1}A$ into a Euclidean ring. Given $\frac{t_1a_1}{s_1},\frac{t_2a_2}{s_2}\in S^{-1}A$, we perform division with remainder $s_2t_1a_1 = qa_2 + r$ such that either $r=0$ or $N(r)<N(a_2)$. Hence, $$\frac{t_1a_1}{s_1} = \frac{q}{s_1t_2}\cdot \frac{t_2a_2}{s_2} + \frac{r}{s_1s_2}$$ and we have $N_{S}\left(\frac r{s_1s_2}\right)=N(r)<N(a_2)=N\left(\frac{t_2a_2}{s_2}\right)$.

Comment: The problem with making $N_S$ with that property is that first you must show that an arbitrary Euclidean function exists in $S^{-1}A$ and then you can create another one having that property (namely, $N(s) \leq N(as)$, $(*)$), using the first one. As I see it, here you are assuming you can define an euclidean function $N_S$ that, a priori, satisfies property $(*)$ and then "construct" it using this property. The only problem I have is that, as I understand, this property requires first the existence of an euclidean function on $S^{-1}A$ and that's what we are wanting to prove, isn't it?

Comment: No, my first statement refers to $N$, not $N_S$. Then I make some hyopthetical statements that are supposed to help you define $N_S$. After all, if any $N_S$ exists, then a multiplicative one exists as well. In fact, assuming $N$ multiplicative you can define $N_S$ which is multiplicative right away. You wanted a hint only. If you want the full solution, read the spoiler.

Comment: @rie: I changed the answer and corrected my mistake thanks to your insightful questions, indeed you have to make sure that $S$ is saturated for the argument to work.

Comment: Thank you very much Jesko, this helped me learn a lot.

Comment: Me too actually. I knew the statement but had never thought about the proof before =).

Comment: If one assumes that $1\in S$, then in the hidden proof, such element $a$ should be divisible by every **non-unit** element in $S$, as it is always divisible by units.

Comment: In addition, we only have $N_S\left(\frac{r}{s_1s_2}\right)\le N(r)$ rather than being equal, because $r$ might be divisible by some non-units in $S$, say $r=t_0a_0$ where $t_0\in S$ and $a_0$ not divisible by any non-units in $S$. Then we have $N_S\left(\frac{r}{s_1s_2}\right)=N(a_0)\le N(t_0a_0)=N(r)$.